# QT: Float to QString

Tags: qt

I am new to QT. I am facing some strange problem in floating point values. The following code displays a message box WITH decimal points. i.e., 10.53

```
QMessageBox Msgbox;
float num = 10.53;
QString str = QString::number(num, 'g', 4);
Msgbox.setText(str);
Msgbox.exec();
```

Where as the following code displays a message box WITHOUT decimal points. i.e., 1

```
QMessageBox Msgbox;
float num = 120/77;
QString str = QString::number(num, 'g', 4);
Msgbox.setText(str);
Msgbox.exec();
```

Why the digits after the decimal point are ignored in the second code snippet? I changed the data type to double and qreal. Nothing worked.

Comment: `float num = 120.0/77.0;` You were doing an integer divisinon, and only cast the result to float **after** the division

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding (float) before the numbers solved the issue. i.e., `float num = (float)120/77;`

Comment: you should mark your own answer as correct to assist future visitors.

Answer (score 5):

because 120/77 is dividing 2 integers (resulting in a integer) and then converting to float

you need to convert the numbers to float before dividing

```
float a = 120, b = 77;
float num = a/b;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
float num = 120.0/77.0;
```

Would also work, standard for C.